# Find the solution that satisfies the conditions of the Schrodinger equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, nonlinear-analysis

The Schrodinger operator with delta potential $H$ is defined as follows:

$$\begin{cases}
D(H) & = \{ u \in H^1 (\mathbb{R}) \cap H^2 (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}); u'(0 +) - u'(0 -) = 2 q u (0)\},\\
Hu &= - \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} u, \hspace{1cm} u \in D(H).
\end{cases}$$

Find the solution $f_{\pm}(x,\xi)$ for the following value problem:

$$\begin{cases}
& Hf_{\pm} = \frac{1}{2} \xi^2 f_{\pm},\hspace{1cm} x \in \mathbb{R}, \xi \in \mathbb{R}\\
 &\lim_{x \to \pm \infty}(f_{\pm}(x,\xi)) - e^{\pm i x \xi} ) =0.
\end{cases}$$

I am studying this very new subject for me and I come cross this problem while I am studying the nonlinear Schrodinger PDE with $\delta$- potential, namely $V(x) = q \delta(x)$ where $\delta$ is Dirac function and $q$ is real number.

**My try**

I would the general solution for the IVP as

$$f_{\pm} (x,\xi) = A e^{\pm i x \xi} + B e^{\mp i x \xi }$$

I was not able to show that $f_{\pm}$ belongs to $D(H)$. Could you please enlighten my about how to solve this problem

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting this correctly, but shouldn't $D(H)\subset L^2(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: @GuachoPerez Yes.

Comment: Then how can $f_\pm \in D(H)$ if $f$ is a linear combination of sines and cosines?

Comment: @GuachoPerez that what confuses me.

Comment: I don't think the problem statement is correct. Intuitively, eigenfunctions correspond to bound states for the problem. In your case, there is nothing stopping the wavefunction from dispersing to infinity.

Comment: @GuachoPerez The problem is right. Just ignore the belonging to $D(H)$.

Comment: @GuachoPerez I seems like what is needed is the solution of the ODE that satisfies the conditions.